# ASP.NET MVC IFrame webform CrystalReportViewer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iframe, webforms

This issue has been bugging me for a few hours. I have an MVC View(Report.cshtml) with an iframe in it. I set the src of the iframe dynamically by passing in the model.
I have a webform(ReportViewer.aspx) which has a crystalreportviewer in it. I pass in the the reportname and parameters as part of query string to this webform.

ControllerCode:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult ViewReport(ReportInfoViewModel _model)
        {
            string _parameterList = "";

            ReportViewerViewModel _rptObj = new ReportViewerViewModel();

            string[] _selected = {"0021", "2000", "0387"};                
                string subParam = "plazaparam=";
                subParam += String.Join(",", _selected);
                _parameterList = string.Concat(_parameterList, "@usrplazaparam=", String.Join(",", _selected));

string _reportSubPath = _model.report_path.Replace("\\", "/");
            string _reportPath = string.Concat("~/Content/Reports", _reportSubPath.Trim());


            string content = Url.Content(string.Format("~/CrystalReports/ReportViewer/ReportViewerForm.aspx?ReportName={0}&Parameters={1}", _reportPath, _parameterList));
            _rptObj.ReportViewerPath = content;
            return View("Report", _rptObj);
}
```

Report.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Report";    
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_rootLayout.cshtml";
}
@model CSC.ViewModels.ReportViewerViewModel


<iframe src="@Model.ReportViewerPath" style="width:100%; height:100%; border:none;"></iframe>
```

ReportViewer.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/ReportSite.Master" CodeBehind="ReportViewerForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="CSC.CrystalReports.ReportViewer.ReportViewerForm" %>


<%@ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" TagPrefix="CR" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" HasCrystalLogo="False" AutoDataBind ="false" Height="100%"  EnableParameterPrompt="false" EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt="false" ToolPanelWidth="200px" 
        Width="100%" ToolPanelView="None"/>     
</asp:Content>
```

ReportViewer.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["ReportDocument"] != null)
            {
                //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "IF", "alert('" + "Session Varialbe != null" + "');", true);
                ReportDocument doc = (ReportDocument)Session["ReportDocument"];                
                CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = null;
                CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = doc;
            }
            else            
            {
                string reportPath = Request.QueryString["ReportName"];
                string parameters = Request.QueryString["Parameters"];
                this.objReport = null;
                Session.Remove("ReportDocument");

                this.objReport = new ReportDocument();
                //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Parameters", "alert('" + parameters + "');", true);
                LoadReport(reportPath, parameters);
            }


        }
```

On Index.cshtml's page submit to ReportsController's ViewReport action, I pass in a dynamically constructed query string "ReportViewer.aspx?ReportName={reportName}&Parameters={parameterString}" to the iframe's src. This code should dynamically load the report specified in the query string dynamically(crystalreportviewer) and show the page. What is happening is that the same report is being loaded and displayed in the new page. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. 
I would appreciate if somebody could point me in the right direction.

Thank you for your help

NH

Comment: Is the `<CR:CrystalReportViewer>` tag something provided by SAP BusinessObjects or did you write it? (if the latter, can you provide that code too?) Also, why did you set `AutoDataBind` to false?

Comment: Thank you for replying so soon. <CR:CrystalReportViewer> tag is a CrystalReportViewer tag that is downloaded from SAP website.

Comment: Controller code: